# Android make bluetooth visible without authorization request

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, bluetooth

it is possible to make bluetooth visible without prompt for permission? I need to activate and make the bluetooth visible in an automatic way.
Thanks in advance for your reply.

in the my MainActivity

```
   private void makeDiscoverable() {
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 0);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    //startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, DISC_DURATION);
    Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
}
```

in the my AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: with out prompt permission u can enable bluetooth by using bluetoothadapter.enable() method.

Comment: I can activate it without problems, but I'm interested in making it visible without request